# Homebrew libtool installation stuck at `rm -rf`

Tags: makefile, installation, homebrew, libtool

`libtool` won't install on my mac via Homebrew *nor* MacPorts (needed for RVM).

This is the verbose output where it hangs forever, running OS X 10.9 & Xcode 4.3

```
    libtool: link: ( cd "libltdl/.libs" && rm -f "dlopen.la" && ln -s "../dlopen.la" "dlopen.la" )
/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link cc  -g -O2 -no-undefined -version-info 10:0:3 -dlpreopen libltdl/dlopen.la   -o libltdl/libltdl.la -rpath /usr/local/Cellar/libtool/2.4.2/lib libltdl/loaders/libltdl_libltdl_la-preopen.lo libltdl/libltdl_libltdl_la-lt__alloc.lo libltdl/libltdl_libltdl_la-lt_dlloader.lo libltdl/libltdl_libltdl_la-lt_error.lo libltdl/libltdl_libltdl_la-ltdl.lo libltdl/libltdl_libltdl_la-slist.lo libltdl/argz.lo
libtool: link: rm -f libltdl/.libs/libltdl.nm libltdl/.libs/libltdl.nmS libltdl/.libs/libltdl.nmT
libtool: link: (cd libltdl/.libs && cc -g -O2 -c -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions  -fno-common -DPIC "libltdlS.c")
brew: superenv removed: -g -O2
libtool: link: rm -f "libltdl/.libs/libltdlS.c" "libltdl/.libs/libltdl.nm" "libltdl/.libs/libltdl.nmS" "libltdl/.libs/libltdl.nmT"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: how did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 6):

I has the same issue, did a bit of tracing and found that is was actually stuck waiting for output to be grepped from the "lipo" command.

Looked around a bit and found the following solution: replace

```
/usr/bin/lipo
```

with the one under

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin
```

and the compilation will work. You need the development environment to be installed.

MrWHO

Comment: Noticed this after updating to Maverics, this fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Rather than replace your system files, most configure scripts will take accept taking lipo as a env variable:

```
export LIPO=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo 
./configure
make
```

Comment: This fixes the same problem on Mavericks, while compiling GSL on 10.9.5. Thanks a lot!! +1!

Answer (score 0):

None of the other solutions worked for me, and, admittedly, my error message wasn't identical but did contain a `rm -rf`, so to whomever this might help:

What got rid of this error for me was adding this line immediately before the call to `make` (well `gmake` really in my case):

```rb
ENV.deparallelize
```

What led me to this was noticing that there was another line in the log output with exactly the same content, but which succeeded, so I reckoned this might be a timing/ordering issue, so `ENV.deparallelize` was the first thing to try.

---

P.S. If anyone could shed light onto why parallelization inside make might be causing this, I'd appreciate that — non-parallel make is so much slower!

UPDATE: adding `env :std` solved the issue for me *without* requiring `ENV.deparallelize`; thanks to `ilovezfs` on #machomebrew for the hint!